# You&#39;ve earned the &quot;Necromancer&quot; badge: Some characters in new global inbox are encoded

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, top-bar

The new global inbox is displaying HTML entities instead of some characters, such as single and double quotes, on notification of earned badges. An example:

> You&#39;ve earned the &quot;Necromancer&quot; badge for Can&#39;t copy text from a pdf file. See your profile.

[image: HTML entities instead of punctuation]